# Magento Enterprise Edition Custom Customer Address Attribute

Tags: magento-2.2.5, magento2-enterprise

I've added custom customer address attribute through the admin panel. The attribute value is inserting in `customer_address_entity_int` table but attribute value is not displaying in Customer Grid.

Any Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To display the value of new attribute you need to make sure that `Add to Column Options` to `Yes` and after that, you need to perform `reindex` command form Magento 2 root directory.

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yes, I've done both. My custom attribute is visible in options but its value is not showing in grid.

Comment: @vejitha facing same issue for customer address attribute, have you got solution?